# Different versions of C/C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I know that I have Java 1.7 and Python 2.7 on my computer. How do I check what version of C and C++ I have? Also, how do I check what C/C++ compiler I am using? I'm running OS X.

Also, what is the relationship between different versions of C/C++ and different versions of **compilers** for C/C++? Does each compiler correspond to a different version of C/C++? For example, would gcc4-3, say, only compile C++2014?

Comment: You have different versions of *compilers*. A compiler can accept various versions of C++ (e.g. the same `g++` with `-std=c++03` or `-std=c++11`...). You should care about ABI compatibility.

Comment: Java compiles and then runs in an emulator, so you're getting the compiler and emulator versions. Python is an interpreted language, so you're getting the version of the interpreter. What you're looking for is your version of [`g++`](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=736078) on your mac.

Comment: 1 question per question

Comment: later C99 has `__STDC_VERSION__` macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I check what version of C and C++ I have?

C++ compiler should define a *preprocessor's const* `__cplusplus`, you can do `std::cout<<__cplusplus<<'\n'` to see in which Standard compiler is running.

> how do I check what C/C++ compiler I am using?

Check in your IDE.

> what is the relationship between different versions of C/C++ and different versions of compilers for C/C++?

Newer compiler may be adapted to newest Standards.

> Does each compiler correspond to a different version of C/C++?

Does MS Office open only files made in newest version? **Nope.**

Answer (score 6):

If you need the C++ standard version, then you should use the '__cplusplus' macro [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#11).

If you mean the compiler version and compiler type, then check [this](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/10/c_c_tip_how_detect_compiler_name_and_version_using_compiler_predefined_macros#Howtodetectthecompilerversion) for all the macros defined by different compilers.

O, btw, compilers are usually backwards compatible. So, a compiler that can compile C++11 code, can compile C++98 as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's _compilers_ that are backwards compatible so much as the language.  In fact, compilers are often _not_ backwards _binary_ compatible.

Comment: @MooingDuck not binary compatible, but they can usually compile codes written with older standards. But you are absolutely right, the standard itself is backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

To get the version of gcc, you can run in the terminal:

```
gcc -v
```

For g++, you can run: `g++ -v`

---

A compiler can compile different versions of C/C++.  So gcc4-3 can compile different versions of C++.

The version of the compiler is independent of the versions of the language.  New versions of gcc contain new features and bugfixes.

Comment: I think some mention of C++ versions is expected as well

Answer (score 0):

> Does each compiler correspond to a different version of C/C++?

No.  There is no correlation between compiler version and the version(s) of the language it supports.

Most current compilers *should* support everything from K&R C to C2011, at least as far as syntax is concerned (some headers may be missing, and the `gets` library function is gone as of the C2011 standard, so *very old* code may break when compiled against the latest standard).  Some compilers such as `gcc` allow you to specify the version of the language you want to build against (`-ansi` for C89/C90, `-std=c99` for C99, and `-c11` for C2011, at least as of gcc 4.9.1).

A notable exception in Microsoft's C compiler in Visual Studio; up until *very* recently, it only supported up to C90.  My understanding is that they are finally starting to support at least *some* of the C99/C2011 changes (such as mixed declarations and code).

As far as C is concerned, the predefined macro `__STDC__` will expand to `1` if at least C90 is supported, and `__STDC_VERSION__`, which will expand to a `long` constant of the form `yyyymmL` if either C99 or C2011 are supported (for example, if the compiler supports up to C99,, then `__STDC_VERSION__` expands to `199901L`.